# trying to join and exploit 5 table in one

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hey everyone here is my code below there is five table,
 what i m trying to do is join and exploit every table with the FACTURE table and the result should be a table with (NUM_CMD/NOM_CLT/PRENOM_CLT/MONTANT_TOTAL_FACT),it mean the name of the client with his command number and the total price of every product he buy(MONTANT_TOTAL_FACT = [PRIX_UNIT]*[QTE])
something like that

```
======================================================
| NUM_CMD | PRENOM_CLT | NOM_CLT | MONTANT_TOTAL_FACT|
====================================================== 
| xxxxxx  | xxxxxxxxxx |    3    |    xxxxxxxxx      |


/*==============================================================*/
    /* Table: CLIENT                                                */
    /*==============================================================*/
    create table CLIENT (
       NUM_CLT              numeric              not null,
       NOM_CLT              text                 null,
       PRENOM_CLT           text                 null,
       VILLE_CLT            text                 null,
       ADRESSE_CLT          text                 null,
       TYPE_CLT             text                 null,
       CP_CLT               text                 null,
       constraint PK_CLIENT primary key(NUM_CLT)
    )



    Insert Into CLIENT Values(1,'Hauari','Kamal','Nador','Hay Matar rue 22','Grossiste','62010');
    Insert Into CLIENT Values(2,'Kharrati','Mohamed','Segangan','Hay zraqtoni rue 50','Grossiste','62100');
    Insert Into CLIENT Values(3,'El Mahi','Noureddine','Salwan','Hay wafae rue 10','Particulier','62000');
    Insert Into CLIENT Values(4,'Chakir','Hassan','Bni nsar','Hay Melilla rue 101','Particulier','62070');
    Insert Into CLIENT Values(5,'Benchikh','Youness','Nador','Hay bouaroro rue 122','Grossiste','62013');
    Insert Into CLIENT Values(6,'Esbai','Fouad','Nador','Hay Regolaris rue 111','Particulier','62090');



    /*==============================================================*/
    /* Table: COMMANDE                                               */
    /*==============================================================*/
    create table COMMANDE (
       NUM_CMD              numeric              not null,
       DATE_CMD             varchar(30)             null,
       NUM_CLT              numeric              not null,
       constraint pk_cmd primary key(NUM_CMD),
       constraint fK_clt foreign key(NUM_CLT) references CLIENT
    )

    Insert Into COMMANDE Values(1,'12-avr-2017',6)
    Insert Into COMMANDE Values(2,'12-avr-2017',5)
    Insert Into COMMANDE Values(3,'12-mai-2017',4)
    Insert Into COMMANDE Values(4,'14-mai-2017',3)
    Insert Into COMMANDE Values(5,'20-mai-2017',2)
    Insert Into COMMANDE Values(6,'30-mai-2017',1)

    /*==============================================================*/
    /* Table: PRODUIT                                               */
    /*==============================================================*/
    create table PRODUIT (
       REF_PRD              numeric              not null,
       DESIGNATION          text                 null,
       PRIX_UNIT            money                null,
       constraint PK_PRODUIT primary key(REF_PRD)
    )


    Insert Into Produit Values(1,'MONITEUR SONY 14P',1580)
    Insert Into Produit Values(2,'MONITEUR ACER 14P',1400)
    Insert Into Produit Values(3,'MONITEUR ACER 17P',4890)
    Insert Into Produit Values(4,'MONITEUR PHILIPS 20P',10500)
    Insert Into Produit Values(5,'MONITEUR PHILIPS 21P',14960)
    Insert Into Produit Values(6,'DESKJET 540',2100)
    Insert Into Produit Values(7,'CANON BJC4000',2700)
    Insert Into Produit Values(8,'EPSON STYLUS',800)
    Insert Into Produit Values(9,'CD ROM MITSUMI 4X',1650)
    Insert Into Produit Values(10,'CD ROM SONY 4X',1980)
    Insert Into Produit Values(11,'CD ROM TEAC 6x',2100)
    Insert Into Produit Values(12,'SCANNER PRIMAX COULEUR',2000)
    Insert Into Produit Values(13,'SCANNER PRIMAX MOBILE',2500)
    Insert Into Produit Values(14,'CARTE SOUND BLASTER PRO',500)
    Insert Into Produit Values(15,'CARTE SOUND BLASTER 16 VALUE',650)
    Insert Into Produit Values(16,'CARIE SOUND BLASTER A WE 32',1680)



    /*==============================================================*/
    /* Table: LIGNE_COMMANDE                                         */
    /*==============================================================*/
    create table LIGNE_COMMANDE (
    NUM_LCMD numeric identity,
       NUM_CMD              numeric              not null,
       REF_PRD              numeric              not null,
       QTE                  int                  null,
       constraint pk_lg_cmd primary key(NUM_LCMD),
       constraint fk_lg_cmd1 foreign key(NUM_CMD) references COMMANDE,
       constraint fk_lg_cmd2 foreign key(REF_PRD) references PRODUIT
    )

    Insert Into LIGNE_COMMANDE Values(6,1,2)
    Insert Into LIGNE_COMMANDE Values(5,2,2)
    Insert Into LIGNE_COMMANDE Values(4,3,7)
    Insert Into LIGNE_COMMANDE Values(3,4,5)
    Insert Into LIGNE_COMMANDE Values(2,5,3)
    Insert Into LIGNE_COMMANDE Values(2,6,2)

    CREATE table FACTURE(
    NUM_FACT int not null,
    DATE_FACT varchar(30),
    NUM_CMD numeric not null,
    REF_PRD numeric not null,
    NUM_LCMD numeric not null,
    NUM_CLT numeric not null,
    MONTANT_TOTAL_FACT float,
    constraint pk_nf primary key(NUM_FACT),
    constraint fk_nc1 foreign key(NUM_CMD) references COMMANDE,
    constraint fk_nc2 foreign key(REF_PRD) references PRODUIT,
    constraint fk_nc3 foreign key(NUM_LCMD) references LIGNE_COMMANDE,
    constraint fk_nc4 foreign key(NUM_CLT) references CLIENT
    );

--i try this one
select NOM_CLT,PRENOM_CLT,NUM_CMD,[PRIX_UNIT]*[QTE] as MONTANT_TOTAL_FACT  from CLIENT,COMMANDE,PRODUIT,LIGNE_COMMANDE,FACTURE where 
CLIENT.NUM_CLT = FACTURE.NUM_CLT and
COMMANDE.NUM_CMD = FACTURE.NUM_CMD and
PRODUIT.REF_PRD = FACTURE.REF_PRD and
LIGNE_COMMANDE.NUM_LCMD= FACTURE.NUM_LCMD;


-- the result was 'Nom de colonne 'NUM_CMD' ambigu'
```

Comment: Did you try something???

Comment: `text` is deprecated. Delcaring your tables using the `text` type will make it impossible to use `GROUP BY`. You should use varchar() instead.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What results did you get?

Comment: @Sami  i add what i m tried look at the last line of my code

Comment: @AichaWahbi **[Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)**

Comment: @GregViers i replace it

Comment: @Sami neccesary to use Inner join ?

Comment: There are so many bad things going on here. Using the text datatype, using varchar for dates, not defining scale or precision for numeric datatypes, using the numeric datatype when int is more appropriate, using float to store the total amounts, using ANSI-89 style joins.

Comment: When you read and try you will know the answer your self.

Comment: @Sami any good habits :D

Comment: `"any good habits :D"` - Foreign keys? :-)   Anything written by Aaron Bertrand is going to be well worth the time to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `INNER JOIN` and `GROUP BY` to get the result you want:

```
select commande.num_cmd, 
       nom_clt, 
       prenom_clt, 
       SUM([PRIX_UNIT]*[QTE]) as total
from commande
inner join ligne_commande on ligne_commande.num_cmd=commande.num_cmd
inner join client on commande.num_clt=client.num_clt
inner join produit on produit.REF_PRD = ligne_commande.ref_prd
group by commande.num_cmd, nom_clt, prenom_clt
```

Comment: Please try to use some aliases here.

Comment: @AichaWahbi Ok, but for what?

Comment: When select `nom_clt` which one you mean? from `commande` table or `client` table?

Comment: @Sami for helping :)

Comment: @Sami Nom and prenom from the client table ,but its working when i run it!!

Comment: It will be a problem with `LEFT / RIGHT` join

Comment: @GregViers any ideas about what Sami says?

Comment: @AichaWahbi nope

Comment: I think Sami is referring to the fact that you select `nom_clt`, but you have `num_clt` in 2 different tables in the `SELECT`. The very similar naming easily can cause confusion, especially when there is no alias on the selected items. `SELECT client.nom_clt` clears it up. If there were two columns in the specified `SELECT`, I believe it would error, but a `SELECT *` would return both columns, and you may not get the results you expected. To make it easier on future maintainers (and yourself) the queries should be aliased and the select columns should be fully specified (`client.nom_clt`).